# How do you size an SWF object based on a Blueprint CSS span range?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flash, blueprint-css

I'm using Blueprint CSS to create a 3 column layout:

```
LEFT COLUMN: span-6
CENTER COLUMN: span-12
RIGHT COLUMN: span-6
```

In the center column I want to place an SWF object which needs a fixed size upon initialization:

```
swfobject.embedSWF(url, "flashDiv", flashWidth, flashHeight, params);
```

I could calculate the initial size relative to the browser window:

```
var flashWidth = window.innerWidth*0.50;
var flashHeight = window.innerHeight*0.50;
```

And resize with jQuery:

```
$(window).height()
```

*But if a Blueprint layout does change based on the browser, then this would seem unnecessary.*

**In that case, how would I calculate the initial width and height relative to the column-width of the center column in this layout (`span-12`)?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd make an HTML element that behaves in the way you want, then embed the Flash in the HTML element sized at 100% x 100%

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I'd suggest thinking a little more about your flashHeight value as is it really likely to be 50% of the height of the page?

Secondly, resizing flash dynamically I don't believe is possible and I wouldn't think it's a good idea if you can. Keep your graphical elements a fixed size and allow the text and freeform elements to flow around them as the page size changes.

Comment: It is possible. I've made use of this several times.

Comment: Okay, it is possible then (which I didn't preclude), still doesn't make it a good idea. Thanks for the downvote though.

Comment: I rescinded my DV. This is where we do it... works quite well actually: http://radiotuna.com/OnlineRadioPlayer/create

Comment: Hey, I'm not that worried about it, I was a little tired when I left that comment. If you feel it's valid then reinstate it, all feedback is good.